# Igus Motor Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, motor

For my work I have to install a linear screw motor from the company [Igus](https://www.igus.com/info/drive-technology-nema-23-ca).
[image]

It will be control with the constructor controller Dryve D1 ([Dryve D1 Doc](https://www.igus.fr/contentData/wpck/pdf/global/Operating%20Manual%20dryve%20D1%20V1.1.PDF)).

[image]

I understood how to connect the motor, the controller and the computer but they don't provide any power supply.

- Have you ever used this king of motor?
- Could you help me to find a power supply or a retailer?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the pin assignments for D1 connectors. X1 is the load connector:
[image]

Further in the datasheet we can see that X1.1 is the positive motor supply voltage, 12-48VDC, X1.2 is 0V for logic and motor supply, and X1.3 is the positive logic supply.

[image]

> Note that the dryve D1 is designed for DC voltages (p18)

So, to answer your question, you would need *at least one* DC power supply to power both motor and logic of the D1, but be careful not to exceed the maximum logic voltage.

The Nema-23 motor you mention has a nominal current of 4.2A, so this is a good baseline. Go with something higher than this so your power supply isn't at risk of cutting out at high current.

[Here are some example AC/DC converters](https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/power-line-protection/power-supplies/ac-dc-converters/ac-dc-enclosed-power-supplies?output-voltage-output-1=24v&output-current-output-1=5a%7C6.25a%7C6.3a%7C6.5a%7C7.5a%7C7.6a%7C8.4a%7C8.8a%7C9.6a%7C10a%7C10.4a%7C10.5a&range=inc-in-stock) with 24VDC and >5A output currents, but you should check the AC voltage and frequency available to you.

I would personally run separate power supplies for motor and logic power, as it makes debugging and management easier in my opinion.